# python - performance difference between the two implementations

Tags: python, performance, sorting

How are the following two implementations have different performance in Python?

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
from itertools import imap
from sys import stdin
input = imap(int, StringIO(stdin.read()))
print '\n'.join(imap(str, sorted(input)))
```

AND

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    l.append(int(line.strip('\n')))

l.sort()
for x in l:
    print x
```

The first implementation is faster than the second for inputs of the order of 10^6 lines. Why so?

Comment: Your second implementation doesn't work (sys.stdin is not callable), and it doesn't do the same thing as the first one (the second one strips the newlines, the first one does not).

Comment: Those two implementations are vastly different. It would take a lot of work to really compare them at the lowest level required

Comment: @Rosh: conversion of string to int in imap will strip '\n' in the first implementation

Comment: So why include the strip in the second version? That's one obvious reason it's slower.

Comment: @Regebro You are right I should remove the strip from 2nd impl. as well. But I think there are more reasons for performance difference than just this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two primary reasons:

- The 2nd code explicitly constructs a list and sorts it afterwards, while the 1st version lets `sorted` create only a internal list while sorting at the same time.
- The 2nd code explicitly loops over a list with `for` (on the Python VM), while the 1st version implicitly loops with `imap` (over the underlaying structure in C).

Anyways, why is StringIO in there? The most straightforward and probably fastest way is:

```
from sys import stdin, stdout
stdout.writelines(sorted(stdin, key=int))
```

Comment: It would have to be `key=lambda l: int(l.rstrip('\n'))` and also it would be less memory consuming if one does `sys.stdout.writelines(x)` versus `print ''.join(x)`. Plus it won't add the additional new-line that wasn't in the input.

Comment: @Rosh Oxymoron: `int('3\n\t               ')` etc works just fine, `int` strips whitespace. You have a good point with `writelines` indeed.

Comment: Can you give more insight into this part of answer: •The 2nd code explicitly constructs a list and sorts it afterwards, while the 1st version lets sorted create only a internal list while sorting at the same time. Ins't 'input' a list similar to 'l' in the 2nd implemntation

Comment: `imap` returns an iterable and not a list. `l` is being constructed inside a Python loop, while the internal list used by `sorted()` is built in a C loop (at least on CPython)

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> dis.dis(first)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (imap)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (int)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (StringIO)
              9 LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (stdin)
             12 LOAD_ATTR                4 (read)
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             21 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             24 STORE_FAST               0 (input)
             27 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             30 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(second)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              48 (to 51)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (sys)
              6 LOAD_ATTR                1 (stdin)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             12 GET_ITER            
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                34 (to 50)
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (line)

  3          19 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (l)
             22 LOAD_ATTR                3 (append)
             25 LOAD_GLOBAL              4 (int)
             28 LOAD_FAST                0 (line)
             31 LOAD_ATTR                5 (strip)
             34 LOAD_CONST               1 ('\n')
             37 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             40 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             43 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             46 POP_TOP             
             47 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   50 POP_BLOCK           

  4     >>   51 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (l)
             54 LOAD_ATTR                6 (sort)
             57 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             60 POP_TOP             
             61 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             64 RETURN_VALUE
```

`first` is your first function.
`second` is your second function.

`dis` tells one of the reasons why the first one is faster.

Comment: Well, it doesn't tell the inner details of the calls that methods like imap, sorted, etc. will in-turn make in first implementation

Answer (score 1):

Do a step-by-step conversion from the second to the first one and see how the performance changes with each step.

1. Remove line.strip. This will cause some speed up, whether it would be significant is another matter. The stripping is superfluous as has been mentioned by you and THC4k.
2. Then replace the for loop using `l.append` with map(int, sys.stdin). My guess is that this would give a significant speed-up.
3. Replace `map` and `l.sort` with `imap` and `sorted`. My guess is that it won't affect the performance, there could be a slight slowdown, but it would be far from significant. Between the two, I'd usually go with the former, but with Python 3 on the horizon the latter is probably preferable.
4. Replace the for loop using `print` with `print '\n'.join(...)`. My guess is that this would be another speed-up, but it would cost you some memory.
5. Add cStringIO (which is completely unnecessary by the way) to see how it affects performance. My guess is that it would be slightly slower, but not enough to counter 4 and 2.

Then, if you try THC4k's answer, it would probably be faster than all of the above, while being simpler and easier to read, and using less memory than 4 and 5. It has slightly different behaviour (it doesn't strip leading zeros from the numbers).

Of course, try this yourself instead of trusting anyone guesses. Also run `cProfile` on your code and see which parts are losing most time.